# How can I create a bounding box and fit text into it?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, text-processing, bounding-box

I'm trying to fit text into a bounding box.
essentially the inputs for the function would be:

1. text -> string (list of words that are separated by ',')
2. width -> int (the set width of the box)

### Example 1:

** If all of the text can fit inside the bounding box and in one line then keep it that way

- Inputs:

  - "test, test2, test3", 100

It should output something like this:

[image]

### Example 2:

** If the text cant fit into the box in one line it would make the box bigger (in height) and just keep writing a line down

- Inputs:

  - "test, test2, test3, test4, test5", 100

It should output something like this:

[image]

### Example 3:

** If the longest string in the list of strings that are separated by `','` cant fit into the box in one line it would make the text smaller

- Inputs:

  - "wikipedia_is_long12345, test, test2, test3", 100

It should output something like this:

[image]

### Another Example:

[image]
I would like some hints/help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried making it again and I did it!

Thats the code:

```
def fit_text(text, text_size, text_color, max_horizontal_chars, box_outline_color, box_background_color,
         box_outline_width, font_file, word_bank_outline, high_res):

"""
:param text: The text that needs to be fir inside the bounding box (words separated by ,)
:type text: str
:param text_size: The size of the text
:type text_size: int
:param text_color: The color of the text
:type text_color: Tuple(int, int, int) | str
:param max_horizontal_chars: The number of the max horizontal chars allowed in one line
:type max_horizontal_chars: int
:param box_outline_color: The color of the outline of the bounding box
:type box_outline_color: Tuple(int, int, int) | str
:param box_background_color: The color of the background of the bounding box
:type box_background_color: Tuple(int, int, int) | str
:param box_outline_width: The thickness of the outline of the bounding box
:type box_outline_width: int
:param font_file: The file of the font of the text
:type font_file: str
:param word_bank_outline: Whether there will be an outline or not
:type word_bank_outline: bool
:return: The image
:rtype: Image
"""
multiplier  = 2
text_size *= multiplier //2

# Replaces every ',' to '-' because the wrapper library will associate '-' as a separator and sorts by length
text = text.split(',')
text.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
text = ','.join(text).upper()
text = text.replace(',', '-')

# Changes the text size to fit the box if the longest word cannot fit in one line
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, text_size)
longest_word = sorted(text.split('-'), key=len)[-1]
if longest_word[0] == ' ':
    longest_word = longest_word[1:]
longest_word_size = font.getsize(longest_word)[0]
while longest_word_size >= 1100:
    longest_word = sorted(text.split('-'), key=len)[-1]
    if longest_word[0] == ' ':
        longest_word = longest_word[1:]
    longest_word_size = font.getsize(longest_word)[0]
    text_size -= 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, text_size)

# Initializes the text wrapper
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper()
wrapper.max_lines = 3
wrapper.placeholder = '...'
wrapper.break_long_words = False
wrapper.width = max_horizontal_chars

# Wrap the text
text = wrapper.fill(text=text)


# Create a new image according to the size of the text
img = Image.new('RGBA', (font.getsize_multiline(text)[0], (font.getsize_multiline(text)[1]+20+(60 if high_res else 20)+box_outline_width+(text.count('\n')*10))), (0,0,0,0))

# Initializes the ImageDraw.Draw for the img so I can draw on it
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im=img)

# If word_bank_outline is true it will draw a bunch or rectangles according to box_outline_width
if word_bank_outline:
    w, h = img.size
    for i in range(0, box_outline_width):
        shape = [(0 + i, 0 + i), (w - i, h - i)]
        draw.rectangle(shape, box_background_color, box_outline_color)

# Replaces every '-' back to ','
text = text.replace('-', ',').upper()

# Checks if the first char is ' ' if it is it will be cut out
if text[0] == ' ':
    text = text[1:]

# Draws the text onto the bounding box
draw.multiline_text(xy=(10 + (20 if high_res else 0), 0), text=text, font=font, fill=text_color, spacing=20)

return img
```

Essentially the main thing that made it happen is the function `ttffont.getsize` which returns the size of a string in pixels and so I could know the exact size of the string and I could fit it more accurately and another thing is the library `textwraper` which divided the text into separate lines.

So first it will check if the longest word in the string can fit inside the bounding box if not it will loop and decrement the text size until it fits
then it will call the textwrapper.fill which will divide the text and then it will just draw the text on the image and draw the outline and then it will return the image.

The end result:
[image]

Comment: The answer would be better if you pointed out exactly what you changed that solved the problem and why it solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Matthew, I changed the answer a little. Is the answer good now? do I need to add more info or anything else?